# Updating an element in an array after limiting the fields to the client

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Let's say I have a `Player` collection and when in the context of a `Game`, it limits their `games` array to only include that game.

```
Meteor.publish('gamePlayer', function (playerId, gameId) {
  check(playerId, String);
  check(gameId, String);

  if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, Roles.getAllRoles().fetch(), gameId)) {
    return Players.find({
      _id: playerId,
      games: {
        $elemMatch: {
          id: gameId
        }
      }
    }, {
      fields: {
        "games.$": 1
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Now I get back the structure I am expecting to get back on the client.

```
// server
> Players.findOne({ _id: "123456" });
{
  _id: "123456",
  battletag: "corvid#1234",
  games: [{
    id: "5678",
    name: "Starcraft II",
    class: "Zerg",
    ladder: 23
  }, {
    id: "1234",
    name: "World of Warcraft",
    class: "Shaman",
    ladder: 123
  }]
}

// client
> var params = Router.current().params;
> Meteor.subscribe('gamePlayer', params.gameId, params.playerId);
> Players.findOne();
{
  _id: "123456",
  battletag: "corvid#1234",
  games: [{
    id: "5678",
    name: "Starcraft II",
    class: "Zerg",
    ladder: 23
  }]
}
```

What I am confused about is how you update an array of objects when you have limited the results fed back in a reliable way. I want to change the limited field's `class` to `Protoss`, for example.

How do you update an array of objects safely on the client in meteor when the fields are limited?

Comment: Which field do you want to update?

Comment: Within the games field, let's say I want to change my class to `Protoss`. I'll update to make it more clear.

Comment: Couldn't you just : `Players.update({_id: params.playerId, 'games.id': params.gameId}, {$set: {'games.$.class': 'Protoss'}});`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue as long as you update the correct `games.id`.

```
Players.update(
  {
    _id: "123456", 
    "games.id": 5678
  }, 
  {
    $set: { 
      "games.$.class" : "Protoss" 
    }
  }
)
```

The client only simulate the update on minimongo while the real update done on server. Whatever changes on server will be propagated back to client.